# Unable to send SMS to India Number through Twilio now

Tags: twilio

My Twilio number is now unable to send SMS to India number (The same numbers to which it was able to send SMS earlier).

I see in the error logs that, the India numbers are getting appended with the number "1". This makes Twilio think that the number is unregistered and I'm getting **Error - 21211**

For Example: `+91 99xxx xxx99` becomes `+191 99xxx xxx99`.

Has anyone faced this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Its stopping my work.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? Do you definitely have the "+" at the start of the number when you try to send it?

Answer (score 0):

On every `Indian mobile number`, there is by default DND service is activated by `TRAI`. If you want to activate the service you have to contact with `Twilio` `support` team on the following mail address 'help@twilio.com'. Then they will ask you for a few details and active the services. There are some links for your reference
To check DND services on your number (`Indian` numbers only)
http://www.nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/search.misc